# Positronium radius more than expected

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, hydrogen, positronium

I am trying to derive the basic properties of positronium. Usually it is stated that we can just set reduced mass of hydrogen atom as $\dfrac{1}{2}m_e$ and obtain:
\begin{equation}
r_n=\dfrac{8\pi\varepsilon_0\hbar^2}{m_ee^2}n^2
\end{equation}
On the other side I am trying to derive that the following way:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0(2R)^2}=\dfrac{m_ev^2}{R}=\dfrac{L^2}{m_eR^3}\quad\text{(2nd Newton's law)}
\end{equation}
Here we assumed that both electron and positron are moving around center of mass in a cirle of radius R, so the distance between them is 2R. Also the quatisation rule for a wave around the orbit:
\begin{equation}
n\lambda=\dfrac{nh}{m_ev}=2\pi R\Rightarrow L=\dfrac{nh}{2\pi}=n\hbar
\end{equation}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
R=\dfrac{L^2 16\pi\varepsilon_0}{m_e e^2}=\dfrac{16\pi\varepsilon_0\hbar^2}{m_e e^2}n^2
\end{equation}
which is 2 times more than needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me firstly point out that according to your assumptions R is still only half the distance of the particles so the result is not wrong by a factor 2 but by a factor 4.

Secondly(See edit below before reading this paragraph): This is mathematically exactly what you would expect when dealing with your semi classical model: increase of particle distance at same distance to center of rotation by factor 2 → decrease of coulomb attraction (equal centripetal force) by factor 4 → decrease of particle speed at any stable classical radius by 2 → increase of De Broglie wavelength by 2 → increase of distance to rotation center according to Bohrs model by 2 → increase of particle distance by 4.

Thirdly: while mathematically correct this calculation is physically pointless if the goal is as stated in your question to calculate properties of a quantum mechanical system like positronium. The correct formula to start from when calculating properties of positronium would be the formula for Hydrogen like Atoms in relative coordinates:

$$\left( -\frac{\hbar^2}{2 \mu} \nabla^2 - \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 r} \right) \psi (r, \theta, \varphi) = E \psi (r, \theta, \varphi)$$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom)

with the inter particle distance $r$ and the reduced mass $\mu$. Since you will use the identical formula for hydrogen and positronium you will also get the identical expression for your Bohr Radius defined as radius with maximum probability of inter particle distance in ground state (Note, that this is not the expectation value). So only the value of your reduced mass will be different, which means that your first formula is correct.

Finally: The Problem here is that Bohrs model has been falsified long ago and while it does give surprisingly accurate results in some special cases, you should never try to expand it for the sake of calculating properties of other quantum mechanical systems, because those results won’t tell you anything as you would still have to confirm that they are agreeing with standart quantum theory or even more elaborate stuff. Today its really just a toy model. In general you should never use “semi-classical” theories unless you are sure that you are operating in one of the limits in witch they are correct.

Edit: After looking at this again I realized that the result of my second paragraph is not the same as the result of your calculation as it predicts a factor 4 compared to Hydrogen while your calculation predicts a factor 4 compared to the true positronium result. This is due to some thinking error on my side due to neglecting the dependece of $v(R)$ when deriving the change of wavelength. I probably should stop trying to visualize stuff like this with this fuzzy arrow diagrams and use equations instead as that is what they are meant for. Anyways I still believe that your result is the mathematically correct prediction of your physically wrong model.

Secondly I just realized that you are using a quantum number in your definition of the Bohr radius which is somewhat incompatible with the definition I use above. The maximum of the probability density in ground state Hydrogen Atom is the only real physical meaning of the Bohr radius I am aware of. I therefore would advice against the usage of higher order radii calculated with Bohrs model for pretty much anything. Feel free to comment if anyone knows any use cases for those.

Comment: amazing, thank you very much!